# Rerender is not working in vf page

Tags: visualforce

Rerender is not working in Vf page. I'm inline updating the list of account record, when I click on update Button then I've to refresh the only PageBlock Table and not the whole page. But PageBlock table in not refreshing.

My Code::-

```
<apex:page controller="RerenderExampleContro">
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock id="test">  
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Assessments" id="Assessments" columns="1" collapsible="true" >
         <apex:commandButton action="{!updateAss}" value="Update Account" style="float:right;" reRender="RefTable"/>

         <apex:outputPanel Id="blockrefresh">
         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account}" var="a"  id="RefTable">
         <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblclick" />

            <apex:column headerValue="Description Sort" style="width:250px">
                <apex:outputField value="{!a.Name}" />
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Last Screening">
                 <apex:outputField value="{!a.Rating}" style="width: 85px;"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column headerValue="Update">
                <apex:outputField value="{!a.type}" style="width: 115px;"/>
            </apex:column>

           </apex:pageBlockTable> 
           </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
 public with sharing class RerenderExampleContro {
 public list<Account> acc;
  public List<Account> getAccount() {
    acc = [select id, name, phone,Rating,type,Industry from Account limit 5];
    return acc;
  }

public PageReference updateAss() {
update acc;
    return null;
}

 }
```

Comment: try re rendering <apex:pageBlock id="test" >,   Like This  reRender="test"/>

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande that also tried, not wokring

Comment: Please share your controller as well. There could be some issue with your controller's `Account`.

Comment: @Mahmood I've update Question with my simple demo controller.

Answer (score 0):

You rerender should be

```
reRender="test,Assessments,blockrefresh,RefTable"
```

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: I mean rerender not reRender

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working **fine** as-is in my dev org. Only correction I made is, I changed

`</apex:pageblock>`

to

`</apex:pageBlock>`

in my code.

Comment: I've change to `</apex:pageBlock>`. but its not working. strange